# excel VBA rename connections

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace existing connections with new import txt file (name myresult.txt) from different folders.
Not sure is there any shortcuts but this is what I did.
Delete existing connection, reimport new connection then rename the connection.
Sheetname/connection name are set in column A of Sheet1 while text file location in Column B. The codes per below but seem like it fails to rename the connection name and cause failure.

```
Sub result_refresh()
Dim i As Integer
Dim textFileLocation, textDelimiter, textData, sheetName
Dim wsheet As Worksheet, file_mrf As String
Dim sh As Range

    'Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")
i = 1
For Each var In Range("A1:A2")
    sheetName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
    textFileLocation = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells.ClearContents
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections(sheetName).Delete
    

    Set wsheet = Worksheets(sheetName)
    file_mrf = textFileLocation
    With wsheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & file_mrf, Destination:=wsheet.Range("A1"))
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .Refresh
    End With
    
   ActiveWorkbook.Connections("myresult").Name = sheetName
    i = i + 1
    
    Next var
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First replace the FOREACH by a FOR..  second, you dont hace a connection with name myresult...  it has been deleted. i think that the automatic name will be Connection, then Connection1, etc